# Hie I am stuck with a problem in webdriver.io where my selector in correct but still its saying selector not found

Tags: javascript, webdriver-io

Heres the code and website is "https://www.seleniumeasy.com/test/basic-checkbox-demo.html" and to clarify Iam trying to click on input element.

```
 it("Check for multiple checkboxes",async()=>{
        // console.log(await checkBox.button.getAttribute('value'));
        let btn = $('#check1');
        await btn.click();
        // expect(await checkBox.button).toHaveText('123 ', { ignoreCase: true })
        await browser.pause(4000)
        

    })
```

Answer (score 0):

My bad never mentioned the url for browser. Thats why it was showing me the error